# How to create an array of objects

Tags: java, class

I thought this was pretty simple, because I am pretty sure I have done it before, but I cant seem to get this to work. 
My class is:

```
public class City
{
    String start = null;
    String end = null;
    int weight = 0;
}
```

and I am doing:

```
City cityGraph[] = new City[l];
```

When I try to access cityGraph[x].start for example, I get a null pointer exception, so I figured I need to initialize every element in the array as well, so I do:

```
for(int j = 0; j < l; j++)
        {
            cityGraph[j] = new City();
        }
```

but it is giving me this error:

```
No enclosing instance of type Graphs is accessible. 
Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance 
of type Graphs (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Graphs).
```

I have no idea what this means, or how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It seems to think you are trying to use type Graphs. Could you post the entire code as is and see if there's a typo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That can happen when you have declared `public class City` as an inner class of `public class Graphs` like so

```
public class Graphs {

    public class City {
    
    }

}
```

This way the `City` cannot be constructed without constructing a `Graphs` instance first.

You'd need to construct the `City` as follows:

```
cityGraph[j] = new Graphs().new City();
// or
cityGraph[j] = existingGraphsInstance.new City();
```

This makes honestly no sense. Rather either extract the `City` into a standalone class,

```
public class Graphs {

}
```

```java
public class City {

}
```

or make it a static nested class by declaring it `static`.

```
public class Graphs {

    public static class City {
    
    }

}
```

Either way, you'll be able to construct a new `City` by just `new City()`.

#### See also:

- [Java Tutorials - Learning the Language - Classes and Objects - Nested Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your class is not a static inner class, which means that it requires an instance of the outer class in order to be instantiated.

More on Static vs Inner classes
http://mindprod.com/jgloss/innerclasses.html

Answer (score 0):

I actually have the answer to my own question. Making the class static fixed it. I don't know why I didn't think of this until after I posted... Hopefully this will help someone in the future.