# Sort Arraylist by property of object

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

So I would like to sort everything out in my ArrayList by using the objects String Name that I have assigned to it.

So far I've read about Comparators to get what I want done. 
But when I implement it, I get a compile error.

I initialize it like this

`private static ArrayList<PeopleInfo> infoArray = new ArrayList<PeopleInfo>();`

and call the sort like this

`Collections.sort(infoArray, new CustomComparator());`

and this is the Class.

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<PeopleInfo> {
    @Override
    public int compare(PeopleInfo o1, PeopleInfo o2) {
        return o1.GetLast().compareTo(o2.GetLast());
    }
}
```

The error I get is 
"No enclosing instance of type mainClass is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type mainClass (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of MainClass)."

Not really understanding what's happening.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you getting this error?? Where is your PeopleInfo class?? And which is your MainClass??

Comment: The problem does not seem to be in the code you have shown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare your Comparator class as a static class

`public static class CustomComparator implements Comparator<PeopleInfo> {`

Comment: Gaaah, something so simple.

Mind explaining why :)?

Comment: There seems to be a fairly decent explanation here, with links to further info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class

Comment: @KelseyAbreu: without the `static` keyword when declaring an inner class - it (the inner class) must have an "attached" instance of the enclosing class. So, you cannot use it (easily) in static methods (such as `main(String[])`). When using the `static` keyword, you let the compiler know it does not need an instance of the enclosing class, and is actually behaving like a normal not nested class.

Comment: Thanks! Some of the most obvious things happen when learning new languages.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can declare comparator outside main class.