# java basic salary program

Tags: java

I am new to java and I keep getting this error message:

> No enclosing instance of type Managesalary is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Managesalary (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Managesalary). on line *

```
public class Managesalary
{
    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
        System.out.println("MY SALARY REVIEW");
        System.out.println("================");


    *   Salary Jan= new Salary();
        Jan.Month= "JANUARY";
        Jan.HoursWorked= 12;
        Jan.PerHourRate= 10;
        Jan.TaxRate= 0.10;

        Jan.printSalaryDetails();

        Salary Month2= new Salary();
        Month2.Month= "FEBUARY";
        Month2.PerHourRate= 10;
        Month2.TaxRate= 0.10;
        Month2.printSalaryDetails();

    }

class Salary
    {
    String Month = "";
    int HoursWorked= 0;
    int PerHourRate= 0;
    double TaxRate= 0.10;
    int MonthlySalary= (HoursWorked*PerHourRate);

    public void printSalaryDetails(){
        System.out.println("MONTH OF = " +Month);
        System.out.println("PER HOUR RATE = " +PerHourRate);
        System.out.println("TAX RATE =   " +TaxRate);
        System.out.println("TOTAL MONTHLY INCOME = " +MonthlySalary);
        System.out.println("================");
    } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible)

Answer (score 2):

The error sais that you have to create a inner class by referencing an instance of the enclosing class.

```
ManageSalary mn = new Managesalary()
Salary salary =  mn.new Salary();
```

Answer (score 2):

Either copy your class Salary in a separate file name Salary.java and make it public, put it outside of you main class preferably above it, or declare it static.

Answer (score 1):

Inner classes need an existing reference to the outer class. Without an instance of `Managesalary` it won't be possible to instantiate `Salary`. You can achieve this by doing:

```
Managesalary mSalary = new Managesalary();
Salary Jan= mSalary.new Salary();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the `Salary` class as an inner class of `Managesalary` (although your code indentation hides this a bit).

Thus, each instance of `Salary` must be bound to an instance of `Managesalary`.

In your `main` method, create an instance of `Managesalary` (e.g. `ManageSalary ms = new ManageSalary()`) and initialize your inner class object as `ms.new Salary()`.

Answer (score 0):

Make your Salary class as static

```
static class Salary{
    // rest of the code
}
```