# Android - Using Connectivity Manager in a Fragment

Tags: java, android, multithreading, http

Okay so i had the problem of network usage in UI Thread and now using AsyncTask. I am using Fragments and have a problem.

When putting this line:

```
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

I have to add getActivity() because its in a fragmetn, then the error goes away but then i get an error on this line:

```
 new DownloadWebpageTask().execute(stringUrl);
```

The error is: "No enclosing instance of type MainActivity is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type MainActivity (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of MainActivity)."

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure this is the code that is getting the error ?

Comment: Yeah, its not a error log, its put the red line under it and gave me that error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your `DownloadWebpageTask` is a non-static nested class of `MainActivity`.

You can make it static by changing it like so:

```
public static class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<..> {
...
}
```

Alternatively, you could create a new `DownloadWebpageTask` by using the instance of `MainActivity`, like so:

```
mainactInstance.new DownloadWebpageTask();
```