# ActionPerfomed Method not working in Inner Class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener, inner-classes

I am a beginner java programmer, trying to implement `ActionListener` through an Inner class. Following is the simple  code where I want to change label text  on button click but instead of using `getSource` for more than one components I want to use Inner Class.   Here is my code :

```
public class InnerClasses extends JPanel  { 

    static   JFrame frame ;     
    static JButton button ; 
    static  JLabel   label  ; 
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        InnerClasses i=  new InnerClasses();    
        frame= new JFrame("Inner class");
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
        frame.add(i);
        label = new JLabel(BorderLayout.NORTH);
        label.setText("I m label");
        i.add(label);    
        button = new JButton(BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        button.setText("Click me ");
        button.addActionListener(new  innerclass() );
        i.add(button);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class  innerclass implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {    
            label.setText("i have been changed");
        }    
    }
```

now when i try to register listener to button it gives error

> No enclosing instance of type InnerClasses is accessible. Must qualify
>   the allocation with an enclosing instance of type InnerClasses (e.g.
>   x.new A() where x is an instance of InnerClasses).

Please help me with it if i am doing something agaisnt the syntax  or whats wrong  here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- to create any GUI required some hierarchy, based on [Oracle tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) and good practicies, code ordering could be important
- don't to create any Swing GUI Objects inside main methods
- I can't found any reason to declare anything static in Java

for example

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class InnerClasses {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JButton button;
    private JLabel label;

    public InnerClasses() {
        label = new JLabel();
        label.setText("I m label");
        button = new JButton();
        button.setText("Click me ");
        button.addActionListener(new MyActioListener());
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(button);
        frame = new JFrame("Inner class");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class MyActioListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            label.setText("i have been changed");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                InnerClasses innerClasses = new InnerClasses();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: there is a problem in this way , if i  put frame etc in Constructor i cant pass instance of my class  ( InnerClasses innerClasses = new innerClasses();)  to frame.add(innerClasses )// this gives error

Comment: @JavaStudent : For that matter simply use `frame.add(this)`, since your `InnerClasses` extends `JPanel`, so no need to create an object of `InnerClasses`, instead use `this` keyword for the same purpose :-) +1 to the answer, which will come in 10 hours :(

Answer (score 2):

Your inner class is not static, so you cannot instantiate it from a static method, and in general, it is better to define inner classes as static, otherwise a new class (not instance) will be created for each instance of the enclosing class:

```
static class  Innerclass implements ActionListener
```

Comment: yes it solved my problem , please explain what do you mean by  " otherwise a new class (not instance) will be created for each instance of the enclosing class:"

Comment: Ejaaaactly, the case, learning C# now a days, so got confused, in which language, the inner class is static by default. This answer did refreshed my memory for that matter :-) +1, to it, though my up-vote will come in 10 hours :(