# Error in Java class

Tags: java, oop, compiler-errors

I am programming in Java, and I came across the following exception...

```
"No enclosing instance of type Host is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Host (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Host)."
```

Here is the relevant code.  Any anyone tell what is causing this exception?

```
//Creating john     
    Employee john =new Employee(Name,Address,Age,Salary);
    //closing the scanner
    in.close();

    john.info();
}
class Employee
{
    //variables
    private String name ="";
    private String address="";
    private double salary=0.0;
    private int age=0;

    //constructor
    public Employee(String n, String add,int a, double s )
    {
        name = n;
        address = add;
        salary = s;
        age = a;        
    }
    public void info()
    {
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(address);
        System.out.println(age);
        System.out.println(salary);
    }
```

Comment: Please be sure to add a tag for the programming language in question. That way people who know that language (Java?) are able to find your questions.

Comment: Also, I know a lot of us give flak for posting too much code, but at the same time, if you leave out important code (where the heck is `Host`?), we can't help at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible)

Answer (score 0):

The error pretty much explains it all. You probably have a non-static inner class in `Host` and you're trying to instantiate it in a static context (i.e. `Host.Inner obj = new Host.Inner()`). You can either make that class static or instantiate it with an instance of the outer class. All this information is available in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html). A simple google search would have revealed that.