# Calculator error with switch Error message java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, calculator

So im trying to make a simple calc but having some problems 
Error message :Multiple markers at this line
    - No enclosing instance of type Application is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance 
     of type Application (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Application).
    - Line breakpoint:Application [line: 64] - main(String[])

What am i doing wrong? Could anyone see something wrong and fix it plz?

```
public class Application {
interface MathOp {
    public double doMath(double a, double b);
    }

    class Add implements MathOp{

      public double doMath(double a, double b) {
        return (a + b);
      }

    }

    class Sub implements MathOp{

      public double doMath(double a, double b) {
        return (a - b);
      }

    }
    class Div implements MathOp{

        public double doMath(double a, double b){
            return (a / b);
        }
    }
    class Mul implements MathOp{

        public double doMath(double a, double b){
            return (a * b);
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {



            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            double a,b,c;
            int choice = 0;
            a=b=c=0.0;
            while(true) {
              System.out.println("Enter two numbers");
              a = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());
              b = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());

              System.out.println("Enter your choice");
              System.out.println("1. Add");
              System.out.println("2. Sub");
              System.out.println("3. Mul");
              System.out.println("4. Div");

              choice = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

              switch(choice) {
               case 1 :
                      c = new Add().doMath(a,b);
                      break;
               case 2 :
                      c = new Sub().doMath(a,b);
                      break;
               case 3 :
                      c = new Div().doMath(a,b);
                      break;
               case 4 :
                      c = new Mul().doMath(a,b);
                      break;
               default:
                       break;

               }
              System.out.println(c + "this is the answere");


              System.out.println("would you like to continue? (Y/N)");
              if("N".equalsIgnoreCase(sc.nextLine())) { // careful with the paranthesis 
                break;
              }
            }
```

}

Comment: Why at all have you made those classes inner classes of `Application`?

Comment: Not really sure why.. im new and im trying to learn how to create diff classes etc

Comment: Well, if you are not sure, just move those classes outside, and then your code would compile.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `Add`, `Sub` etc classes are *inner classes*, which means you have to have an instance of the containing class... which you don't at this point.

Options:

- (Best!) Get rid of your interface, instead creating an `enum` (at the top level; not nested) which has one member for each operation. The enum would declare an abstract method, which would then be overridden in each member:

  ```
  public enum MathOperation {
      ADDITION { 
          @Override public double doMath(double a, double b) {
              return a + b;
          }
      },
      SUBTRACTION { 
          @Override public double doMath(double a, double b) {
              return a - b;
          }
      }
      // etc
      ;

      public abstract double doMath(double a, double b);
  }
  ```
- (Okay) Keep the interface and the implementation classes, but move them outside your `Application` class. Nested types should be pretty rare, IMO.
- (Not great) Add the `static` modifier to each of the implementation classes. They'd still be nested, but they wouldn't require an implicit reference to an instance of `Application`.
- (Urrgh!) Create an instance of `Application` so that you can create an instance of your operation classes. **Don't do this. I'm only including it for completeness.**

While nested classes can certainly be useful, if you're relative newcomer to Java I suggest you avoid them for now. They come with their own rules and syntax which can be a little odd to start with. Stick with declaring all your types at the top level instead.

Comment: I was expecting the first one to be (Best!). :)

Comment: @RohitJain: I bow to your preference :)

Comment: You made my weekend :)

Comment: i put them outside app class and its working just having a trouble with the system outprint the result

Comment: @user2825771: No, don't put them inside a different class - that would be just as bad. Each one should be its own top-level class (or interface). You'd typically put each one in its own source file, too.

Comment: @user2825771: Well without you saying what the problem is, it's hard to help you with that. But if you really can't work it out, please add a new question.