# Custom ArrayList, Passing data between Classes

Tags: android, arraylist

I have a fragment activity with a custom arraylist format

```
    public class giftsListFormat {
        String id;
        String name;
        String url;
        String points;
    }
    ArrayList<giftsListFormat> giftList = new ArrayList<giftsListFormat>();
```

I am trying to access this list format from an asynctask class

```
private static class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

 private MyAsyncTask () {
   [How can i create an object of giftsListFormat here?]
   [How can i access giftList from here]
 }
  }
```

Comment: you can send your list as a parameter to constructor of your class, define one constructor for `MyAsyncTask` that get one `List<giftsListFormat>` and in Activity pass your list to this constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - This may be the custom class that you need.

Declare this as global :

```
ArrayList<giftsListFormat> details = new ArrayList<giftsListFormat>();
```

---

```
    public class giftsListFormat {
    String id;
    String name;
    String url;
    String points;

    public String getid() {
    return id;
    }
    public void setid(String id)
    {
    this.id = id;
    }

    public String getname() {
    return name;
    }
    public void setname(String name)
    {
    this.name = name;
    }

    public String geturl() {
    return url;
    }
    public void seturl(String url)
    {
    this.url = url;
    }

    public String getpoints() {
    return points;
    }
    public void setpoints(String points)
    {
    this.points = points;
    }
}
```

---

To put the value into the array list - Do this

```
    giftsListFormat Detail;
    Detail = new giftsListFormat();
    Detail.setid("test1");
    Detail.setname("test2");

    details.add(Detail);
```

---

Now to retrieve the values
 put the following code inside the async task

```
details.get(i).id.toString();
details.get(i).name.toString();
details.get(i).url.toString();
```

You can iterate over the size of the array list.

```
details.size();
```

Comment: Hi Bala, thanks for the response.
I have tried to create a giftsListFormatClass. When i try to access the same in my asynctask class
giftsListFormat tmpGiftFormat;
tmpGiftFormat=new giftsListFormat();
It throws "No enclosing instance of type GiftItemsListActivity is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type GiftItemsListActivity (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of GiftItemsListActivity)."

Comment: You can try refering the following post for this.
 Its quite simple, You can resolve it.
 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744639/must-qualify-the-allocation-with-an-enclosing-instance-of-type-geolocation
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19141792/no-enclosing-instance-of-type-test-is-accessible-must-qualify-the-allocation-wi

Answer (score 0):

Make "giftList" global variable in your activity.
Send the context to your AsyncTask through Constructor.
Now you can access that variable as follows:

```
private static class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
 ArrayList<giftsListFormat> giftList;
 private MyAsyncTask (Activity activity) {
    giftList = activity. giftList;
      giftsListFormat ref = giftList.get(pos);
 }
  }
```

Comment: Hi Rama, thanks.
But, what if i need to create an object of type giftsListFormat?

Comment: i don't think so make global value is a right Decision, why OP don't send list to the constructor instead of context?

Comment: yes you can send that arrayList as parameter.It is every thing based on your requirement.

Comment: In fact, i would need to add items to the giftList after parsing a json object inside the asynctask. 
JSONObject currentRecord = (JSONObject) resultsArray     .get(i);
giftsListFormat tmpFormat=new giftsListFormat(); 
tmpFormat.id=(String) currentRecord.get("IDN");           tmpFormat.name=(String) currentRecord.get("ItemNameCN");            tmpFormat.points=(String) currentRecord.get("Cost");            tmpFormat.url=(String) currentRecord.get("Image");            System.out.println(tmpFormat);
//to the main list          giftList.add(tmpFormat);

Answer (score 0):

create a giftsListFormat class like:

```
public class giftsListFormat{
    String id;
    String name;
    String url;
    String points;

 //create constructure  and assign parameters which you want to set   
   public giftsListFormat(String id, String name,String url, String points){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.url = url; 
    this.points = points;
   } 

  public getId(){
  return id;
  }

  public getName(){
  return name;
  }

  public getUrl(){
  return url;
  }

  public getPoints(){
  return points;
  }
}
```

And use this class like: `ArrayList<giftsListFormat>...`

Inside `AsyncTask` set all your data at the time of initialization..like:

```
giftsListFormat mData = new giftsListFormat(id, name, url, points);
```

And when you want to get just use get methods...