# How to solve this compile error?

Tags: java

I get this error "no enclosing instance of type oppgave1 is accessible", when i wrote "new Triangle();". I need som help to explain me where i did wrong (about the triangle class). I'm new beginning in java.Thanks for advance.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Triangle T1 = new Triangle(1, 1, 1, "green", false);

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter three sides of the triangle: ");
    double side1 = input.nextInt();
    double side2 = input.nextInt();
    double side3 = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter a color: ");
    String color = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter true or false (to indicate triangle is filled or no): ");
    String isFilled = input.nextLine();
}

public class GeometricObject {
    //Data fields
    private String color = "blue";
    private boolean filled;

    //The default geometricObject/constructor
    public GeometricObject() {
        this("No color", false);
    }
    //The geometricObject with the specified colour and filled value
    public GeometricObject(String color, boolean filled) {
        this.color = color;
        this.filled = filled;
    }
    //Returning the colour
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    //Setting a new colour
    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
    //Returning the filled
    public boolean isFilled() {
        return true;
    }
    //Setting a new filled
    public void setFilled(boolean filled) {
        this.filled = filled;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return (color + " - " + filled + " - ");

    }
}

public class Triangle extends GeometricObject {

    //Data fields
    double side1 = 1.0;
    double side2 = 1.0;
    double side3 = 1.0;
    //no-arg constructor
    Triangle(){
        this(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, "No color", false);
    }
    //A constructor that creates a triangle with the specified sides
    public  Triangle(double side1, double side2, double side3, String color, boolean filled) {
        this.side1 = side1;
        this.side2 = side2;
        this.side3 = side3;
        setColor(color);
        setFilled(filled);
    }
    //Returning the sides 
    public double getside1() {
        return side1;
    }
    public double getside2() {
        return side1;
    }
    public double getside3() {
        return side1;
    }
    //setting the new ones
    public void setSide1(double side1) {
        this.side1 = side1;
    }
    public void setSide2(double side2) {
        this.side2 = side2;
    }
    public void setSide3(double side3) {
        this.side3 = side3;
    }
    //getting the rule
    /* public void setSide(double side1, double side2, double side3) {
        if (((this.side1 +  this.side2) >  this.side3 ) && ((this.side2 + this.side3) > this.side1)
                && ((this.side1 + this.side3) > this.side2))
                System .out.println("The rule (the sum of any two sides is greather"
                        + " than the other side) is adhered"); 

    } */
    //Returning area
    public double getArea() {
        double p = ((side1 + side2 + side3) / 2);
        double area = Math.sqrt(p * (p - side1) * (p - side2) * (p - side3));
        return area;
    }
    //Returning perimeter
    public double getPerimeter() {
        return (side1 + side2 + side3);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return (super.toString() + "Triangle: side1 = " + side1 + "side2 = " + side2 + " side3 = " + side3 +'\n'+
                "Area i: " + getArea() + '\n' + "Perimeter is: "  + getPerimeter()) ;
    }
 }
```

}

Comment: Your Triangle constructor has default visibility, maybe your main method lives in another package? Make it public and you should be fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Triangle` is currently an *inner class* - which means you can only create it by also having an instance of the enclosing class. Simple options:

- Make `Triangle` a top-level (non-nested) class.
- Make it a *static* nested class
- Provide an instance of the enclosing class when constructing an instance of `Triangle`

(See the [Java tutorial for more on nested/inner classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).)

Personally I'd recommend the first course of action - nested classes can certainly be useful, but I'd recommend using top-level classes unless there's a specific *benefit* from a nested class.

Additionally, even though you *can* put multiple classes in the same source file if at most one of them is public (and therefore has the same name as the file) I'd recommend putting each top-level class in its own file, named according to the class.

Comment: In this specific case it seems like Triangle should be its own class with its own file.

Comment: @odedsh: Indeed - a top-level class.

Comment: what do you mean by indeed a top level class? i'm ny beginner javas user and i want to understand what i'm doing. Thx

Comment: @Kurt16: Did you follow the link in the answer, or search for "top level class" and Java? It's important to be able to do some of the research for yourself.

Comment: To be honest..not yet(saturday: spending day with my family). But I'll do it seriously, otherwise thank you for your answer & advice.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the nested/inner classes now. I moved Triangle out of the Oppgave1 (norwegian, means excercise1)class. But, the code refuses to compile and i can't find where the pbm is. Can you help me with that (if you can tell me which line nr. the pbm is?)

Comment: @Kurt16: How am I meant to know which line number the problem is on? Your compiler will tell you that. I suggest you do what you can to find the problem, and then ask a new question with all the relevant information - including the error message and which line it occurs on.

Comment: I found where the pbm was and i'm trying to resolve the remainder. Thanks for your help.