# No Enclosing instance error

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, jcomponent, mouse-listeners

So I'm working through a Java book and I've come to this program. However when I'm working with it in Eclipse it gives me a No Enclosing Instance of type .... error

I'm pretty baffled by this as to why this error pops up. Here is my code:

I've commented the line that gives the error

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class HelloJava2 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello, Java2!");
        /*
        HelloComponent2 newObject = new HelloComponent2("Hello, Java!");
        */
        frame.add(newObject);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    class HelloComponent2 extends JComponent implements MouseMotionListener
    {
        String theMessage;
        int messageX = 125, messageY = 95;

        public HelloComponent2(String message)
        {
            theMessage = message;
            addMouseMotionListener(this);
        }

        public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
        {
            g.drawString( theMessage, messageX, messageY);
        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
        {
            messageX = e.getX();
            messageY = e.getY();

            repaint();
        }

        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) 
        {

        }
    }
}
```

If anyone could explain why I'm getting this error and how to fix/avoid it in the future I would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: **Where** do you get the error?

Comment: Either your braces are wrong, or you forgot the `static` keyword.

Comment: `HelloComponent2` has to be static if you need it from main

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are trying to instantiate a non-static inner class from a static method.

Java has two kinds of inner classes that can be nested at the class level - static and non-static. Non-static classes have a reference to an *instance* of their "outer" class, inside of which they were instantiated. This allows non-static inner classes access instance variables of their outer class. Static classes, such as your `HelloComponent2`, do not access instance variables of their outer class. This lets you instantiate such classes from static functions.

Making the class `static` should fix the problem:

```
static class HelloComponent2 extends JComponent implements MouseMotionListener
```

Comment: this not to help somehow :-) isn't better (correct direction for OP) to use, call, rename to the standard constructor (HelloJava2) instead of suggest to declaring something to static ....

Comment: @mKorbel It looks like this code has been retyped from a book. It is very easy to miss the `static` part while typing, especially the error appears in a seemingly unrelated place.