# Android AsyncTask error in declaration

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm getting this error "No enclosing instance of type Datagetter is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Datagetter (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Datagetter)." and my code is

```
public static void initializeValues
    (String _NAMESPACE , String _URL , String _SOAP_ACTION , 
String _METHOD_NAME , String _PARAM_NAME , String _PARAM_VALUE)

    {
        NAMESPACE = _NAMESPACE ;
        URL = _URL ;
        SOAP_ACTION = _SOAP_ACTION ;
        METHOD_NAME = _METHOD_NAME ;
        PARAM_NAME = _PARAM_NAME ;
        PARAM_VALUE = _PARAM_VALUE ;
        TAG = "Name of log" ;


        AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
        //Call execute
         task.execute();

    }
```

**AsyncCallWS**

```
public class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
            getDataFromWebservice();
            return null;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");
        //    tv.setText(fahren + "° F");
        }


        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");
         //   tv.setText("Calculating...");
        }


        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onProgressUpdate");
        }

    }
```

Comment: For which line you are getting that error?

Comment: AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS(); this line gives me error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you creating the new object in "static" method. You should add the modifier "static" to AsyncCallWS class such as :

```
public static class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> { ...... }
```

Answer (score 6):

The method where you are instantiating the asynctask is `static`. However, the `AsyncCallWS` seems to be a non-`static` inner class. Non-static inner classes hold a reference to the parent and therefore cannot be accessed without the parent object.

Probably your async task should be declared `static` - most often having an asynctask non-static is a programming error.

Answer (score 0):

Change your method signature

```
public static void initializeValues()
```

to

```
public void initializeValues()
```