# How to call inner class method inside the main method?

Tags: java

I am creating a class Perfect inside the main class and in Perfect class i am creating a method perf() and i want to call this method in the main method..how to do it?

My code is here

```
public class Fib {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            }

    class Perfect {

        void perf(){
            int sum = 0;
            int count = 0;

            for(int i=6; i<=10000; i++){
                for(int j=1; j<=i/2; j++){
                    if(i%j==0){
                        sum+=j;
                    }
                }
                if(sum==i){
                    count=count+1;
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
                sum=0;
            }

            System.out.println("Total perfect number is : "+count);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `new Fib().new Perfect().perf()`

Comment: Is there a reason why you want `Perfect` to be an inner class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible)

Answer (score 3):

`new Fib().new Perfect().perf()` should work fine

Comment: Interesting.  I guess I've learned something about Java today.  For reference, I was able to find more information here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9560600/328193

Comment: @David: you also got Duplicate question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write in this form

```
    Fib outer = new Fib();
    Perfect inner = outer.new Perfect (); 
    System.out.println(inner.perf());
```

Comment: did you try to compile that code? perf() returns void, nothing "printable" by System.out.println(), just take off that System.out.println()

Answer (score 0):

You can call inner class method inside the main method.

you have to make inner class as static, then you can directly access by `className.MethodName()`. There is not a necessity of creating object..

**Example:**

```
package com;

public class Fib {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Perfect.assign(5);
       }

   private static class Perfect {      
       static void assign(int i) {
           System.out.println("value i : "+i);
       }

    }
}
```

Here, `Perfect` is inner class, `assign` is a method which is place inside inner class... Now i just call inner class method by `className.MethodName()`.

When you run this program you will get an **Output:** `value i : 5`

Hope this helps.!!