# no enclosing instance of type... in scope

Tags: java, inheritance, instantiation, inner-classes

I investigate java inner classes.

I wrote example:

```
public class Outer {
    public Outer(int a){}

    public class Inner {
        public Inner(String str, Boolean b){}
    }

    public static class Nested extends Inner{
        public static void m(){
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
        public Nested(String str, Boolean b , Number nm)   { super("2",true);   }
    }

    public class InnerTest extends Nested{
        public InnerTest(){  super("str",true,12);  }
    }
}
```

I invoke it from main using following string:

```
 new Outer(1).new Inner("",true);
```

I see compile error:

```
  java: no enclosing instance of type testInheritancefromInner.Outer is in scope
```

Can you explain me this situation?

**UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: Please post the full code.

Comment: What's this `testInheritancefromInner`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`Inner` is an inner class. It can only be created when there is an enclosing instance of the class containing the `Inner` class definition.

However, you've created a `static` nested class, `Nested`, which extends from this class. When you try to invoke the super constructor

```
public Nested(String str, Boolean b , Number nm)   { super("2",true);   }
```

it will fail because the super constructor, for `Inner`, depends on an instance of `Outer`, which doesn't exist in the `static` context of the `Nested` class. [Jon Skeet provides a solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22117161/438154)

An explanation of the solution appears in the JLS [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7.1).

> Superclass constructor invocations may be subdivided:
>
> - Unqualified superclass constructor invocations begin with the keyword
>     super (possibly prefaced with explicit type arguments).
> - **Qualified superclass constructor invocations begin with a Primary
>     expression.**
>
>   - **They allow a subclass constructor to explicitly specify the newly
>       created object's immediately enclosing instance with respect to the
>       direct superclass (§8.1.3). This may be necessary when the superclass
>       is an inner class.**

Answer (score 21):

As Sotirios has said, your nested (not-inner) class doesn't *implicitly* have an instance of `Outer` to effectively provide to the `Inner`.

You *can* get round this, however, by *explicitly* specifying it before the `.super` part:

```
public Nested(String str, Boolean b, Number nm) { 
    new Outer(10).super("2", true);
}
```

Or even accept it as a parameter:

```
public Nested(Outer outer) { 
    outer.super("2", true);
}
```

However, I would *strongly* advise you to avoid such convoluted code. I avoid nested classes most of the time, named inner classes almost always, and I can't ever remember using a *combination* of them like this.

Comment: the reference to an instance of outer class to use in a constructor like `outer.super()` can be not only a parameter, but also a field. This way you can quietly extend an inner class being outside its outer class.