# Android - "No enclosing instance of type 'some.abstract.class.name' class is in scope" error when extended

Tags: java, android, abstract-class, extends, android-viewholder

I have an abstract adapter class from an external library:

```
public abstract class DragItemAdapter<T, VH extends DragItemAdapter.ViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VH> {
    //Their other codes
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ViewHolder(final View itemView, int handleResId) {
            super(itemView);
            //The rest of their codes
        }
    }
}
```

And I have my Adapter extended that adapter

```
public class ChecklistAdapter extends DragItemAdapter<Pair<Integer, SomeClass>, ViewHolderForChecklist> {

    @Override
    public ViewHolderForChecklist onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
          View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
          grab = R.id.grab;
          return new ViewHolderForChecklist(view,grab);
    }
}
```

If my `ViewHolderForChecklist` is an inner class of the `ChecklistAdapter` it works fine. But if I move the `ViewHolderForChecklist` to a brand new class

```
public class ViewHolderForChecklist extends DragItemAdapter<Pair<Long, SomeClass>, ViewHolderForChecklist>.ViewHolder { // The error is at this line

    public ViewHolderForChecklist(final View itemView, int grab) {
        super(itemView, grab);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClicked(View view) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClicked(View view) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

There is an error in real time

> No enclosing instance of type 'library.package.name.DragItemAdapter' class is in scope

and the error when compile

> error: an enclosing instance that contains DragItemAdapter.ViewHolder is required

Using "move" from Refractor has the same problem. I'm still new to this kind of... 'nested-class" so I don't know what is wrong with this or what kind of info should I include more.

Thank you!

Comment: Kind of similar, have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22117161/3931910

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ViewHolder` is an *inner class* of `DragItemAdapter` (because it wasn't declared `static`).  That means that every object of class `ViewHolder` must be associated with an object of class `DragItemAdapter` (actually, it would have to be a subclass of `DragItemAdapter`).  You can think of `ViewHolder` having a hidden instance variable like

```
DragItemAdapter __outerObject;
```

The `ViewHolder` can directly access instance variables and methods belonging to the `__outerObject`.

That means that when you say `new ViewHolder(...)`, you have to have some `DragItemAdapter` for the `ViewHolder` to be associated with.

The same applies to any subclass of `ViewHolder`, including `ViewHolderChecklist`, since the subclass inherits the hidden `__outerObject` variable.

In the first example, where `ViewHolderChecklist` is inside a `ChecklistAdapter`, the `onCreateViewHolder` method will always be called on a `ChecklistAdapter` instance.  When that method says `new ViewHolderChecklist`, the new object's `__outerObject` will be set to the `ChecklistAdapter` instance.  Also, if an outside class has a `ChecklistAdapter adapter;`, it can use that to create a new `ViewHolderChecklist` by saying `adapter.new ViewHolderChecklist(...)`.

When you move `ViewHolderChecklist` outside the class, though, there's no way for a new instance to be created, since there's no way to use `new` in a way that would tell it what its `__outerObject` is supposed to be.  The `adapter.new ViewHolderChecklist(...)` syntax won't work, because that syntax is only allowed for nested classes, and `ViewHolderChecklist` isn't a nested class.  So `ViewHolderChecklist` has to be a nested class inside a subclass of `DragItemAdapter`.

**Correction:** It's actually possible to declare `ViewHolderChecklist` like this.  However, you have to give it an explicit constructor and it has to have a Qualified Superclass Constructor Invocation (see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#d5e14278); see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40501642/what-rule-prohibits-this-nested-class-reference/40501815.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. Your conclusion of "has to be a nested class" is what proves it impossible and it saves a lot of time looking for a solution.

Comment: Please see my correction, although most likely it involves a construct you wouldn't want to use.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at that.

Comment: Wow, just edit a few lines and it works. Pass an instance of `ChecklistAdapter` to the viewholder `return new ViewHolderForChecklist(view,grab,this);` then use that instance to call super `adapter.super(itemView, grab);` in `ViewHolderForChecklist` class.
But can you tell me why you said "you wouldn't want to use"? I think it's kinda simple

Comment: Well, then, **I** wouldn't want to use it.  It seems to me that it could make the code more obscure.  On the other hand, if there are good reasons to do things that way, those reasons might outweigh my objections.  Maybe someday I'll run across a case where I'll want to use this.