# Creating instance of inner class outside the outer class in java

Tags: java, class, inner-classes

I'm new to Java.

My file `A.java` looks like this:

```java
public class A {
    public class B {
        int k;
        public B(int a) { k=a; }
    }
    B sth;
    public A(B b) { sth = b; }
}
```

In another java file I'm trying to create the A object calling

```java
anotherMethod(new A(new A.B(5)));
```

but for some reason I get error: `No enclosing instance of type A is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type A (e.g. x.new B() where x is an instance of A).`

Can someone explain how can I do what I want to do? I mean, do I really nead to create instance of `A`, then set it's `sth` and then give the instance of `A` to the method, or is there another way to do this?

Comment: B does not depend on A so it would make sense to make it static (`public static class B`) - your code will then work. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible

Comment: Well, I don't know why I didn't think of using `static`, but it's the solution in fact. Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your example you have an inner class that is always tied to an instance of the outer class.

If, what you want, is just a way of nesting classes for readability rather than instance association, then you want a static inner class.

```
public class A {
    public static class B {
        int k;
        public B(int a) { k=a; }
    }
    B sth;
    public A(B b) { sth = b; }
}

new A.B(4);
```

Comment: Well, I don't know why I didn't think of using `static`, but it's the solution in fact. Thanks. I'll acept your answer in 9 minutes when I'll be able to do so.

Answer (score 35):

Outside the outer class, you can create instance of inner class like this

```
Outer outer = new Outer();
Outer.Inner inner = outer.new Inner();
```

In your case

```
A a = new A();
A.B b = a.new B(5);
```

For more detail read [Java Nested Classes Official Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Comment: This is excellent advice in most cases.  +1.  However, it won't work in this case, because there's no default constructor for `A`.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting puzzle there. Unless you make `B` a static class, the only way you can instantiate `A` is by passing `null` to the constructor. Otherwise you would have to get an instance of `B`, which can only be instantiated from an instance of `A`, which requires an instance of `B` for construction...

The `null` solution would look like this:

```
anotherMethod(new A(new A(null).new B(5)));
```