# Access from Class C to value from inner Class B of Class A

Tags: java, class, methods

I don't understand why I can't even make a new instance, IDE marks inner class name as unassigned

```
public class WbXLS {

  class XlsCell {
    public String getxlsCell(HSSFSheet sheet, String strCellValue) {

    }
  }
}
```

Tried without success

```
WbXLS.XlsCell xlscell = new wbXLS.new XlsCell();
```

I made the inner class to get return value from method and use it in another class. Am I right doing so?

Comment: this actually compiles?? WbXLS.XlsCell xlscell = new wbXLS.new XlsCell (); try making the nested class static, and -> new WbXLS.XlsCell();

Comment: @Stultuske it's a problem, I need an inner class, not nested. In the outer class I work with xls workbook '...main void' and the inner class isn't nested because I think it will work so only with full access to outer class.

Comment: inner classes are (non-static) nested classes

Comment: @Stultuske, static is prohibited. I tried it, syntax error..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating instance of inner class outside the outer class in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24506971/creating-instance-of-inner-class-outside-the-outer-class-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be missing brackets. This compiles for me:

```
WbXLS.XlsCell xlscell = new WbXLS().new XlsCell();
```

Answer (score 0):

Every `XlsCell` object has a `WbXLS.this` : a reference to the object container it resides in.

So parenthesis were missing:

```
WbXLS.XlsCell xlscell = new WbXLS().new XlsCell();
```

But in effect you probably want:

```
WbXLS workbook = new WbXLS();
WbXLS.XlsCell xlscell = workbook.new XlsCell();
```

And do something with one single workbook instance. (For which several cells may be created.)