# An error regarding Exception Handling in JAVA

Tags: java

I am newly learning Java Event handling. I wrote a code but it shows an error while I try to call a Constructor of class MyGUI from the main method. Please have a look and explain the following error to me.

Error:

```
No enclosing instance of type MyGUI is accessible. Must qualify the allocation 
with an enclosing instance of type MyGUI (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance 
of MyGUI).
```

My code:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;


public class MyGUI extends JPanel {
    JButton button;
    JTextField textField;
    JRadioButton radioButton;

    MyGUI(){
    add(new JButton("Button"));
    add(new JTextField(10));
    add(new JRadioButton("RadioButton"));

    }


     class MyHandler implements ActionListener
    {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if(e.getSource()==button)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Button has been clicked");
            }
            else if(e.getSource()==textField)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "TextField has been clicked");
            }
            else if(e.getSource()==radioButton)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "RadioButton has been clicked");
            }

        }

    }

public static void main(String[]args)
{
    MyGUI gui=new MyGUI();

    MyHandler handler=new MyHandler();    //Error Shows on this statement
    gui.button.addActionListener(handler);


    JFrame frame=new JFrame("Its a frame");
    frame.add(gui);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT,10,10));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



}
}
```

Comment: So..what is the error?

Comment: `MyHandler` class is nested within MyGUI. You need to refer to it as `MyGUI.MyHandler`.

Comment: If you want others to help you debug, you need to add more details. Imagine I came up to you and said "here is my code I'm getting an error", what would be your first question? Same here, what does the error state?

Comment: @colti when i call the new MyHandler() constructor, it shows an error.

Comment: @raiyan106 You'll need to be more specific.

Comment: @scrappedcola yes you are right man. I am sorry. The following error shows "No enclosing instance of type MyGUI is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type MyGUI (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of MyGUI)."

Comment: @raiyan106 you need to make your question make more sense by including more details that will help one understand your promble. Also showing the error message will important

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible)

Answer (score 2):

The `main` method isn't the one to be setting up action listeners for `MyGUI`.  Move the code that sets up the action listeners into the `MyGUI` constructor.

You'll also need to assign the new components you're creating to your instance variables.

```
MyGUI(){
    button = new JButton("Button");
    textField = new JTextField(10);
    radioButton = new JRadioButton("RadioButton");

    add(button);
    add(textField);
    add(radioButton);

    MyHandler handler = new MyHandler();
    button.addActionListener(handler);
}
```