# a new instance of a class extends TimerTask can not be instantiated from the main

Tags: java, android, timertask

I have the below `timed task`:

```
static TimerTask timedTask = new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("timed task");
    }
};

//main method
main(...) {
Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(timedTask, (long) logfile.getFileHash().get(1).getTimeStampInMilli());
}
```

what I want to do is, to create a class that exteds `TimerTask` so that I can create a new `timerTask` when ever i want. but the problem is when i create the class as follows:

```
class TimerTask2 extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

the line

`timer.schedule(new TimerTask2(), (long) logfile.getFileHash().get(i).getTimeStampInMilli());` is higlighted by ecipse and says:

> No enclosing instance of type File_IO is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type File_IO (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of File_IO).

i tried to qualify te class instance with the main class name but also it did not work.

kindly please provide suggestions for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add static modifier to TimerTask2:

```
static class TimerTask2 extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    }
}
```

Comment: this is because main() is static and TimerTask2 is defined inside main's class. This is the same as if you tried to read a non-static field from static method.