# Creating objects with multiple classes

Tags: java, class

I have a program with multiple classes, and when I try to make an instance of one of these objects in main, I get an error. How do I properly create a class in main with multiple classes?

```
public class A {

    class B {
    }

    class C {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        C c = new C();
    }
```

Error: No enclosing instance of type A is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type A

Comment: you can make the inner classes static, then they don't need an enclosing instance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `B` and `C` are inner classes. Unless you understand inner classes, this is probably not what you want.

Move them outside `A`:

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        C b = new C();
    }
}
class B {
}
class C {
}
```