# Chat Java - Trouble with Server

Tags: java, server

Hello everyone!

So yes, Im trying to make a chat function with Java. The problem is that I have two classes. One for Client and one for ClientGUI. Where the Client one has the Logic things and the ClientGUI the design. The problem is getting is in row 46 where `new ListenFromServer().start();` is getting a error

"    No enclosing instance of type Controller is accessible. Must
         qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type
         COntroller(e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Controller).  "

I hope someone could help me with this!

```
**Controller (Client logic)** 

package Server;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;




public class Controller {

    private static ObjectInputStream input;
    private static ObjectOutputStream output;
    private static Socket socket;
    private static ClientGUI clientgui;

    private static String username;
    private static String server;
    private static int port;



    public static boolean startClient(){

        try{
            socket = new Socket(server, port);
        }catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.print("Error connecting to the server: " + ex);
            return false;
        }

        String message = "Connection is accepted; " + socket.getInetAddress() +" - "+  socket.getPort();
        System.out.println(message);


    try {
        input=new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        output =new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    }
    catch (IOException io) {
        System.out.print("Exception creating new Input/Output Stream: "+ io);
        return false;

    }

    **********new ListenFromServer().start();********* //The problem is here

    try {
        output.writeObject(username);
    }
    catch(IOException io) {
        System.out.print("Exception doing login: " + io);
        disconnect();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
    }

    private void display(String message) {
        if(clientgui == null)
            System.out.println(message);
        else
            clientgui.append(message +"\n");
    }

    public static void sendMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            output.writeObject(message);
        }
        catch(IOException exd) {
            System.out.print("Eceptionwritingtoserver: " + exd);
        }
    }

    private static void disconnect() {
        try {
            if(input != null)
                input.close();
        }catch (Exception ex){}
        try{
            if(output != null)
                output.close();
        }catch(Exception ex){}
        try{
            if(socket != null)
                socket.close();
        }catch(Exception ex){};

        if (clientgui != null)
            clientgui.connectionFailed();
        }

    public class ListenFromServer extends Thread{


        public void run() {
            while(true){
                try{
                    String message = (String) input.readObject();
                    if(clientgui == null){
                        System.out.println(message);
                        System.out.print(":");
                    }
                    else {
                        clientgui.append(message);
                    }
                }
                catch(IOException io){
                    System.out.print("Server has closed the connection");
                    if(clientgui != null)
                        clientgui.connectionFailed();
                    break;
                }
                catch(ClassNotFoundException classex){

                }

                }


            }

        }

    }
```

**ClientGUI**

```
    package Server;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;


    /*
     * The Client with its GUI
     */
    public class ClientGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private JLabel lblusername;

        private JTextField textfieldusername, textfieldserver, textfieldportnumber;

        private JButton btnlogin, btnlogout, btnonline;

        private JTextArea textareamessage;

        private boolean connected;

        private Client client;

        private int defaultPort;
        private String defaultHost;


        ClientGUI(String host, int port) {

            super("Chat Client");
            defaultPort = port;
            defaultHost = host;


            JPanel northPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));
            JPanel serverAndPort = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2, 2, 2));
            JLabel lblserveraddress = new JLabel("Server Address:  ");
            JLabel lblchat = new JLabel("                #BallIsLife");
            JLabel lblportnumber = new JLabel("Port Number:  ");

            textfieldserver = new JTextField(host);
            textfieldserver.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
            textfieldserver.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
            textfieldportnumber = new JTextField("" + port);
            textfieldportnumber.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
            textfieldportnumber.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);

            lblserveraddress.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 19));
            serverAndPort.add(lblserveraddress);
            serverAndPort.add(textfieldserver);
            serverAndPort.add(lblchat);
            serverAndPort.add(lblportnumber);
            serverAndPort.add(textfieldportnumber);
            lblchat.setForeground(Color.RED);
            lblportnumber.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 19));
            northPanel.add(serverAndPort);
            getContentPane().add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            JPanel panelbtn = new JPanel();
            northPanel.add(panelbtn);


            btnlogin = new JButton("Login");
            panelbtn.add(btnlogin);
            btnlogin.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 17));
            btnlogin.addActionListener(this);

            btnonline = new JButton("Online");
            panelbtn.add(btnonline);
            btnonline.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 17));

            btnonline.addActionListener(this);
            btnonline.setEnabled(false);        

            btnlogout = new JButton("Logout");
            panelbtn.add(btnlogout);
            btnlogout.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 17));
            btnlogout.addActionListener(this);
            btnlogout.setEnabled(false);        

            JButton btnPicture = new JButton("Picture");
            btnPicture.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 17));
            btnPicture.setEnabled(false);
            panelbtn.add(btnPicture);


            textareamessage = new JTextArea("Welcome to the #BallIsLife Chat room.\n");
            textareamessage.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 15));

            textareamessage.setLineWrap(true);
            textareamessage.setEditable(false);

            JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,1));
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textareamessage);
            centerPanel.add(scrollPane);
            getContentPane().add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


            JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
            getContentPane().add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            lblusername = new JLabel("Enter your username", SwingConstants.CENTER);
            lblusername.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
            southPanel.add(lblusername);

            textfieldusername = new JTextField("Write your username here.");
            textfieldusername.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
            textfieldusername.setColumns(50);

            southPanel.add(textfieldusername);


            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setSize(823, 665);
            setVisible(true);

        }

    //Logiken

        void append(String str) {
            textareamessage.append(str);
            textareamessage.setCaretPosition(textareamessage.getText().length() - 1);
        }


        void connectionFailed() {
            btnlogin.setEnabled(true);
            btnlogout.setEnabled(false);
            btnonline.setEnabled(false);
            lblusername.setText("Enter your username");
            textfieldusername.setText("Write your username here");

            textfieldportnumber.setText("" + defaultPort);
            textfieldserver.setText(defaultHost);

            textfieldserver.setEditable(false);
            textfieldportnumber.setEditable(false);

            textfieldusername.removeActionListener(this);
            connected = false;
        }

        //

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Object button = e.getSource();

            if(button == btnlogout) {
                Controller.sendMessage(new Message("", Message.LOGOUT)); //Ändra till Chatmessage klass
                btnlogin.setText("Login");
                return;
            }

            if(button == btnonline) {
                Controller.sendMessage(new Message("", Message.ONLINE));    //Ändra till Chatmessage klass          
                return;
            }


            if(connected) {

                Controller.sendMessage(new Message(textfieldusername.getText(), Message.MESSAGE)); //Ändra till Chatmessage klass       
                textfieldusername.setText("");
                return;
            }


            if(button == btnlogin) {

                String username = textfieldusername.getText();

                if(username.length() == 0)
                    return;

                String server = textfieldserver.getText();
                if(server.length() == 0)
                    return;

                String portNumber = textfieldportnumber.getText();
                if(portNumber.length() == 0)
                    return;


                int port = 0;
                try {
                    port = Integer.parseInt(portNumber);
                }
                catch(Exception en) {
                    return;  
                }


                client = new Client(server, username, port, this);

                if(!Controller.startClient()) 
                    return;

                }

                connected = true;

                textfieldusername.setText("");
                btnlogin.setText("Send message");


                btnlogin.setEnabled(true);

                btnlogout.setEnabled(true);
                btnonline.setEnabled(true);

                textfieldserver.setEditable(false);
                textfieldportnumber.setEditable(false);

                textfieldusername.addActionListener(this);
            }



        // to start the whole thing the server
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new ClientGUI("localhost", 1500);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this, nested classes. If a nested inner class is *not* static, it can access the outer object and its fields. Here the class Inner has an `Outer.this`. For an allocation with `new Inner()` one then has to provide an Outer object: `outer.new Inner()`. In general one might first try to make the inner class static to see whether the outer class is needed.

```
class Outer {

    String s;

    void p() {
        StaticInner x = new StaticInner();
        Inner y = this.new Inner();
    }

    static class StaticInner {

         void f() {
             // CANNOT use field s.
         }
    }

    class Inner {

        int n;

        void g() {
            n;
            this.n;
            this;
            Outer.this;
            Outer.this.s;
            s;
        }
    }
}
```

---

The easiest would be to make your inner class "static."

```
public static class ListenFromServer extends Thread{
```

In general one would remove everywhere `static` and create just one Controller object. That saves typing.

Comment: This is little too hard for me to understand. Could you give exempel with my code? I tried to change class ListenFromServer extends Thread{ to a static but then it gives a another error :                                     Error connecting to the server: java.net.ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine. And also, If I change public static boolean startClient(){ to a non-static. It gives a error in ClientGUI "if(!Controller.startClient()) 
    return;" where I need to have a static to make it work. @Joop-eggen

Comment: after your update. What I now got is: Error connecting to the server: java.net.ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine

Comment: The server with a ServerSocket and `accept` I have not seen; it must be waiting on that socket.

Comment: Do you need the other classes to make it easier for you?

Comment: It's Friday and I am going in the weekend in a couple of minutes and will be offline for a period. It is a bit much code. You might look at other code; sometimes one can use a nice code snippet, or see what one overlooked.

Comment: Oh i appreciate your time and i hope everything will go well for your weekend. I will try see that the problem can be but i doubt it. Hope someone here could help me out :)