# Sorting an UnsortedGrouping does not work - No enclosing instance of type MyClass is accessible

Tags: java, apache-flink

I am trying to group a DataSet by a parameter, then sort the result by applying a `sortGroup` function. Finally I want to apply a reduceGroup function to obtain a transformed DataSet.

```
DataSet<SlicedTile> slicedTilesSorted = stitchedTimeSlices.flatMap(new sliceDetailedBlocks(detailedBlockSize, blockSize))
    .groupBy(new KeySelector<SlicedTile, Tuple2<Integer, Integer>>() {
        public Tuple2<Integer, Integer> getKey(SlicedTile s) { 
            return s.getPositionInTile(); 
        }
    }) 
    .sortGroup(new SlicedTileTimeKeySelector<SlicedTile>(), Order.ASCENDING)            
    .reduceGroup(new approxInvalidValues());
```

But Eclipse shows an error at the sortGroup line which states:

> No enclosing instance of type MyClass is accessible. Must
>   qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type
>   MyClass (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of
>   MyClass).

Could anybody please tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible)

Comment: In other words, it seems that `SlicedTileTimeKeySelector` is an inner class within `MyClass`. To fix the problem, you should declare it as `static` (`static class SlicedTileTimeKeySelector`).

Comment: Thanks for your help this solved the issue.