# how to initiate an object from an extended class in java

Tags: java, inheritance, initialization, extends

I've a mother class livre.

Bd & album are two extended classes from Livre

I've a problem on the main(), I can't initiate & declare an object (myAlb) from the class album: here is what i did:

album[] myAlb;

myAlb= new album[nbr_of_albums];

myAlb[i] = album(1,5,"author","title"); // for an album i I call the constructor of album= error

here is the error: No enclosing instance of type livre is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type livre (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of livre).

here is my full code source:

```
import java.util.*;

public class livre {

public abstract class book {
    String titre;
    String auteur;
    float prix;
    int nbr_pages;
    book(String titre,String auteur, float prix,int nbr_pages){
        this.titre = titre;
        this.auteur = auteur;
        this.prix = prix;
        this.nbr_pages = nbr_pages;
    }
    abstract void affichage();
}
public class bd extends book {
    String couleur;
    bd(String titre,String auteur, float prix,int nbr_pages,String couleur){
        super(titre,auteur,prix,nbr_pages);
        this.couleur = couleur;
    }
    void affichage(){
        System.out.println("\n\nbook:"+titre);
        System.out.println("+ auteur"+auteur);
        System.out.println("+ prix"+prix);
        System.out.println("+ nbr_pages"+nbr_pages);
        System.out.println("+ "+couleur);
    }

}
public final class album extends book {
    String [] couleur;
    void changerCouleur(){
        int nbr = 0;
        System.out.print("Plz set the nbr of the page that you want to color: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (!(nbr<= nbr_pages && nbr > 0 )){ nbr = sc.nextInt();}
        System.out.print("Plz set what color u wanna colorate this page: ");
        couleur[nbr] = sc.nextLine();
        sc.close();
    }
    void affichage(){
        System.out.println("\t\t book:"+titre);
        System.out.println("+ auteur"+auteur);
        System.out.println("+ prix"+prix);
        System.out.println("+ nbr_pages"+nbr_pages);
        System.out.println("+ couleurs des pages: ");
        for(int i=0;i<nbr_pages;i++) System.out.println("   =>Page["+i+"]= "+couleur[i]);
    }
    album(String titre,String auteur, float prix,int nbr_pages){
        super(titre,auteur,prix,nbr_pages);
        couleur = new String[nbr_pages];
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    album[] myAlb; bd[] myBd;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Set the nbr of Albums that you want to make: ");
    int nbrAlbum = sc.nextInt();
    myAlb= new album[nbrAlbum];
    System.out.print("Set the nbr of BD that you want to make: ");
    int nbrBd = sc.nextInt();
    myBd= new bd[nbrBd];
    for(int i=0;i<nbrAlbum;i++){
        System.out.print("\tAlbum nbr "+i+": ");
        System.out.print("=>titre = ");
        String titre = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("=>auteur = ");
        String auteur = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("=>prix = ");
        float prix = sc.nextFloat();
        System.out.print("=>nbr de Pages = ");
        int nbr_pages = sc.nextInt();
        myAlb[i] = new album(titre,auteur,prix,nbr_pages);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Please format your code properly. Also, please post the exact compiler error.

Comment: my code is well formatted I suppose. and yes i did post the compiler error:
No enclosing instance of type livre is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type livre (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of livre).

Comment: It pretty much looks like each of your inner classes (book, bd, album) should be static, and that alone would fix your code.

Comment: Your code is not well-formated (there is a indentation missing on the level of the class) and you did not post the exact compile error. A compiler error always tells the exact line of the error.

Comment: @Turing85 sorry I guess that i wasn't that clear it's on: "myAlb[i] = new album(titre,auteur,prix,nbr_pages);"  i mentioned it on the top

Comment: @LouisWasserman my bad, works like a charm, can you please give me more details on why we should use static ? i read here that we use it if a class method don't change directly its attributes i guess that this is not true

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `public abstract class book` with `public static abstract class book`

And replace `public final class album extends book` with `public final static class album extends book`

That should work. Adding `static` modifier allows you to instantiate an inner class without having an instance of the enclosing class. You have the book class as an inner class, that's why you need the `static` modifier.

If you also want to instantiate `bd` class, you should also put `static` for it.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code can be rewritten as below:

public class livre {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    abstract class book {
        String titre;
        String auteur;
        float prix;
        int nbr_pages;
        book(String titre,String auteur, float prix,int nbr_pages){
            this.titre = titre;
            this.auteur = auteur;
            this.prix = prix;
            this.nbr_pages = nbr_pages;
        }
        abstract void affichage();
    }

    class bd extends book {
        String couleur;
        bd(String titre,String auteur, float prix,int nbr_pages,String couleur){
            super(titre,auteur,prix,nbr_pages);
            this.couleur = couleur;
        }
        @Override
        void affichage(){
            System.out.println("\n\nbook:"+titre);
            System.out.println("+ auteur"+auteur);
            System.out.println("+ prix"+prix);
            System.out.println("+ nbr_pages"+nbr_pages);
            System.out.println("+ "+couleur);
        }

    }

    final class album extends book {
        String [] couleur;
        void changerCouleur(){
            int nbr = 0;
            System.out.print("Plz set the nbr of the page that you want to color: ");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            while (!(nbr<= nbr_pages && nbr > 0 )){ nbr = sc.nextInt();}
            System.out.print("Plz set what color u wanna colorate this page: ");
            couleur[nbr] = sc.nextLine();
            sc.close();
        }
        @Override
        void affichage(){
            System.out.println("\t\t book:"+titre);
            System.out.println("+ auteur"+auteur);
            System.out.println("+ prix"+prix);
            System.out.println("+ nbr_pages"+nbr_pages);
            System.out.println("+ couleurs des pages: ");
            for(int i=0;i<nbr_pages;i++) System.out.println("   =>Page["+i+"]= "+couleur[i]);
        }
        album(String titre,String auteur, float prix,int nbr_pages){
            super(titre,auteur,prix,nbr_pages);
            couleur = new String[nbr_pages];
        }
    }


    album[] myAlb; bd[] myBd;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Set the nbr of Albums that you want to make: ");
    int nbrAlbum = sc.nextInt();
    myAlb= new album[nbrAlbum];
    System.out.print("Set the nbr of BD that you want to make: ");
    int nbrBd = sc.nextInt();
    myBd= new bd[nbrBd];
    for(int i=0;i<nbrAlbum;i++){
        System.out.print("\tAlbum nbr "+i+": ");
        System.out.print("=>titre = ");
        String titre = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("=>auteur = ");
        String auteur = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("=>prix = ");
        float prix = sc.nextFloat();
        System.out.print("=>nbr de Pages = ");
        int nbr_pages = sc.nextInt();
        myAlb[i] = new album(titre,auteur,prix,nbr_pages);

    }
}
```

}

For more info on nested class follow the below link:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html