# Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Main (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Main)

Tags: java

How to fix below error? I need quick help.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem: 
>         No enclosing instance of type Main is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Main (e.g. x.new A()
>   where x is an instance of Main).
>
> at com.common.Main.main(Main.java:16)

Here is my code for reference. If we fixed that this issue then `"John"` should be printed only once and not twice. **How we can restrict `"John"` to print once**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Person> l = new HashSet<Person>();
        l.add(new Person("John"));
        l.add(new Person("John"));
        l.add(new Person("Matt"));
        l.add(new Person("Deepak"));
        l.add(new Person("Chris"));

        for (Iterator iterator = l.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Person person = (Person) iterator.next();
            System.out.println(person.getName());
      }
    }

    public class Person{
        private String name;

        public Person(String name) {
            super();
            this.setName(name);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `Person` class doesn't look like it should be an inner class (i.e. it doesn't look like it requires an associated instance of the enclosing `Main` class), make it static (i.e. a nested class of the `Main` class, which doesn't require an enclosing instance) :

```
public static class Person { ...
```

or move it outside your `Main` class.

EDIT :

As for your second issue, override `equals` and `hashCode` in your `Person` class, in order to let `HashSet` know when two objects should be considered identical :

```
public boolean equals (Object other) {
    if (!(other instanceof Person))
        return false;
    Person op = (Person) other;
    return this.name.equals(op.name);
}

public int hashCode () {
    return name.hashCode();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Though I use set but still why John is printing twice? I only want to print it once. What should I changed. Currently the Output I am getting Chris
John
John
Matt
Deepak

Comment: @user4567570 That's a different issue. In order for your `HashSet` to function as you wish, you must override `equals` and `hashCode` in your `Person` class, so that two `Person` instances having the same name will be equal to each other and have the same `hashCode`.

Answer (score 1):

`Person` is an inner class of `Main` and since it's not static `main` can't access it.