# Eclipse Java thread

Tags: java, multithreading

Java program on thread, it seems to be alright but there's something wrong at `UserThread ut1 = new UserThread(5, "Thread A");`

Program:

```
public class Ch10_2_2 {

    class UserThread extends Thread {
        private int length;
        public UserThread(int length, String name){
            super(name);
            this.length = length;
        }

        public void run() {
            int temp = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++)   temp += i;
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + "Sum = " + temp);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread());

        UserThread ut1 = new UserThread(5, "Thread A");
        UserThread ut2 = new UserThread(5, "Thread B");

        ut1.start();    ut2.start();
    }
}
```

Error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem: No enclosing instance of type Ch10_2_2 is accessible. Must
>   qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Ch10_2_2
>   (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Ch10_2_2). at
>   Ch10_2_2.main(Ch10_2_2.java:21)

Comment: make it a static class. `static class UserThread...`

Comment: Exactly :)  thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your `UserThread` class to be `static`.

Currently, you're trying to access an "instance" class from a static context, which is invalid. Making your nested class `static` will allow you to access it from a static context without error.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible) for more information.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This is the correct solution.

Comment: If the `inner` class is static then there will only be `one` right?  As the OP is instantiating two of them in a non thread-safe manner, then this is not the solution that he wants.

Comment: @Scary Wombat : That is incorrect. Whether a class is defined as static or not there will only be one definition of it in the ClassLoader. The difference is in how you reference that definition. If a nested class is not static it cannot be referenced directly. An instance of the outer class is required i.e. `NestedClass c = new OuterClass().new NestedClass() `