# No enclosing instance of type is accessible. Error and can any body help me ive been trying changing everything but no result

Tags: java, multithreading

i have been trying to runout the multithread but i get the error can any one help me , i have been changing the hole lot but i havent found the way to sort out the problem: "No enclosing instance of type programa4 is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type programa4 (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of programa4)."
Thanks for all.

```
public class programa4 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int t=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int x=1;            

    String z=args[1];

            while(x<=t){
                System.out.println("Iniciando hilo "+x);
                new hilo(z).start();
                x=x+1;
            }
}   
class hilo extends Thread{
int num;
String z;
hilo(String z){
    this.num=Integer.parseInt(z);
}

public void run() {
    int t=1;
    while(t<=num){
    System.out.println("Generando iteracion: "+ t);
    double x=Math.random()*10;
    System.out.println("Esperando "+ x +" segundos");
    try {
        Thread.sleep((long)x*1000);
        System.out.println("Iteracion terminada");


    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Se interrumpio.");
    }
    t=t+1;
    }
    System.out.println("Terminado hilo.");

}
}   
}
```

Comment: `static class hilo extends Thread` - add **static**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `hilo` is an `inner class` of `programa4` there must be an isnstance of `programma4` first before you can create an inner for it.

Making it `static class hilo` breaks that requirement.

```
static class hilo extends Thread {
```

The alternative would be to create a `programa4` to attach it to.

```
new programa4().new hilo(z).start();
```