# Error: No enclosing instance of type Main is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Main (e.g. x.new A() wh

Tags: java, arrays, variables

My code does not work. I  get the following error:

> No enclosing instance of type Main is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Main (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Main).

You see my code in the following:

```
class Main {

public class Room {
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + etage;
        result = prime * result + gebäude;
        result = prime * result + raumnummer;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Room other = (Room) obj;
        if (etage != other.etage)
            return false;
        if (gebäude != other.gebäude)
            return false;
        if (raumnummer != other.raumnummer)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public int gebäude;
    public int etage;
    public int raumnummer;

    public Room(int gebäude, int etage, int raumnummer) {
        super();
        this.gebäude = gebäude;
        this.etage = etage;
        this.raumnummer = raumnummer;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String s = String.format("%2s-%s.%02d", this.gebäude, this.etage, this.raumnummer);
        return s;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Room office = new Room(17, 0, 10);
    Room lecture = new Room(2, 0, 10);
    Room lab = new Room(18, 1, 1);

    System.out.println(office);  // => "17-0.10"
    System.out.println(lecture); // => " 2-0.10"
    System.out.println(lab);     // => "18-1.01"
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION 1**

Separating the class Room from the class Main did the trick for me:

File Main.java:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Room office = new Room(17, 0, 10);
    Room lecture = new Room(2, 0, 10);
    Room lab = new Room(18, 1, 1);

    System.out.println(office);  // => "17-0.10"
    System.out.println(lecture); // => " 2-0.10"
    System.out.println(lab);     // => "18-1.01"
}
}
```

File Room.java:

```
public class Room {
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + etage;
        result = prime * result + gebäude;
        result = prime * result + raumnummer;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Room other = (Room) obj;
        if (etage != other.etage)
            return false;
        if (gebäude != other.gebäude)
            return false;
        if (raumnummer != other.raumnummer)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public int gebäude;
    public int etage;
    public int raumnummer;

    public Room(int gebäude, int etage, int raumnummer) {
        super();
        this.gebäude = gebäude;
        this.etage = etage;
        this.raumnummer = raumnummer;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String s = String.format("%2s-%s.%02d", this.gebäude, this.etage, this.raumnummer);
        return s;
    }
}
```

Let me investigate why this happens and I will post the reason. By now, this is a suitable fix if you don't need both classes to be on the same file.

**SOLUTION 2**

Make room static:

```
...
class Main {

public static class Room {
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
...
```

**WHY THIS HAPPENS**

As stated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible), by having Room as an inner class of Main, you are forcing the instances of Room to have an instance o Main. When using the operator new on the inner class Room without making a new instance of Main an error is produced.

By making the class Room static the class doesn't need an instance of Main.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `Room` is an inner class of `Main`, but is not declared as a `static` member. When you have a non-static inner class, it can only be instantiated using an object of the outer class, otherwise the expression `Main.this` (which is legal in the inner class) would not have an instance of `Main` to refer to. Since the `main` method is `static`, there is no `Main` instance to pass to the `Room` constructor.

The solution is simply to replace the declaration `public class Room` with `public static class Room`.